# Apache hangs after resending POST data

Tags: apache, post

Apache 2.4.33 on Windows 7 x64, no virtual host hangs after re-sending post data to the server. Example scenario HTML POST form was sent to server the server returned 200 OK, hitting F5 to refresh the page the browser ask to resend POST form data answering Yes results Apache hanging for almost a minute and then I got 408 Request Timeout error message from Apache.

Edit: local webserver in office, workstation not accessible from outside.

Comment: Put your `LogLevel debug`, restart, try again.  The page that receives the second POST, does it interact with anything else (i.e. database, other service, ...).  That external resources might not know what to do with duplicates.

Comment: I've tried on a simple php page not database, no service what so ever, the problem still persists. I have the debug log here https://pastebin.com/rAVbwAF4

Comment: I think there is something wrong on the SSL side, this effect does not occur when I access the page without SSL, I post, hit F5, it works. Could you provide me some guidance what's wrong, if you need I can share my SSL config too if it helps.

Comment: I am not saying it is the issue, but you probably get certificate errors in your browser when you try to access your page, since the log shows that you tried to open 127.0.0.1, and the certificate is for the name.  Sadly, besides that, I see nothing worth mentioning in the log file...

Comment: It is ok I discovered that when I was testing that without SSL when I send the form and hit F5 the servers responds instantly. Sadly I am not an expert in SSL either; yesterday I was searching for solution but I have no clue which keywords to use which eventually would bring up some guide or test tools. I've had some luck with cURL connecting to the server some ssl_v3 handshake error, SSLCertificateChainFile errors were reported. But as I said I don't have the knowledge yet to solve this. Anyhow, thank you your support and kindness.